# Best query that return result after update in elasticsearch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-structures, nosql, mapping, data-warehouse

Recently I work on a store website where users could order from mobile applications and the admin could search over user data in the admin dashboard, I use elastic search as a search engine in my rails apps. Store admin could create custom queries and retrieve their custom results, for each user who orders by the mobile app I create two custom indexes and insert them on elastic. these indexes are user profile data and user events. In profile User profile collected like first name, last name... and in the event, I collect user actions like login sign up...Users in the mobile app could update him/her profile so each time I have to create a profile index and insert it in my elastics. I have a problem, assume a user-created profile with this informations:

```
profile-2022-05-29
    {
      "event": "sign_up",
      "profile_id": 1,
      "profile": {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "helen"
      }
    }
```

and next day update her profile with new data like this:

```
profile_2022-05-30
    {
      "event": "sign_up",
      "profile_id": 1,
      "profile": {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "rose",
        "last_name": "brown"
      }
    }
```

So I have two different profile indexes in my elastic for one user now if I want to find a user the last name is "brown" and have the event "sign_up" Elastic only returns the last index "**profile-2022-05-30**" document, that is the user profile with updated information but I expect that elastic return both indexes document because the user updates her profile so I have two indexes for one user.
Does anyone could help me what is the best query DSL in elastic that returns both indexes.

this is my elastic query:

```
GET profile_*/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "last_name": "brown"
              }
            },
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "event": "app_open"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Updated: Each time I want to query over my data I search over all of my indexes like this:

```
Get profile_*
{
"some query"
}
```

Comment: Can you please add more details as your question is not clear. Also, query which you ahve provided is not valid query as `match` query dont support two field name togather.

Comment: @Sagar Patel What kind of details could you please tell me?

Comment: I wonder, why are you not updating the existing document ? You would not have multiple documents.
Else you could add a timestamp to each document and order then by date

Comment: Can you please add details like what all index you have (name of index) etc.  `Elastic only returns the last index` what do you mean by this ? do you mean document ? because you have not given URL which you are using for query and if you are passing only one index name then it will return documents fron only one index.

Comment: I think OP might be making a slight confusion between document and index

Comment: I could not update it because the user could update her profile in few date later and In my system I have more than 7000 user so it's hard to find and update them it's better to save data even with duplicate.about timestamp if i add timestamp should i change my query to two query?